# postfix - how to send out queued emails at a specific time

Tags: linux, email, postfix

I am using Postfix and my goal is that Postfix queues my emails.  For example, until it's  08:00am (my time) and then sends emails out whole day until it is 21:00.  It is only allowed to send out emails between 08:00am and 09:00pm.
I have already setup postfix and can queue my emails, but the time schedule is something I can not find an answer to. Not sure, if this is possible, but hopefully someone can help me here.

My main.cf file. If that helps.

```
# See /usr/share/postfix/main.cf.dist for a commented, more complete version


# Debian specific:  Specifying a file name will cause the first
# line of that file to be used as the name.  The Debian default
# is /etc/mailname.
#myorigin = /etc/mailname

smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Debian/GNU)
biff = no

# appending .domain is the MUA's job.
append_dot_mydomain = no

# Uncomment the next line to generate "delayed mail" warnings
#delay_warning_time = 4h

readme_directory = no

# See http://www.postfix.org/COMPATIBILITY_README.html -- default to 2 on
# fresh installs.
compatibility_level = 2



# TLS parameters
smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
smtpd_use_tls=yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache

# See /usr/share/doc/postfix/TLS_README.gz in the postfix-doc package for
# information on enabling SSL in the smtp client.


smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
myhostname = brandon.local
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
myorigin = /etc/mailname
mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain, $mydomain
relayhost =
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a few ways you could potentially go about it.  One way is to simply use iptables to block outgoing port 25 using a cron job.  For example, if you have

```
-A OUTPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 25 -j CURFEW
-A CURFEW -j ACCEPT
```

then to disable you'd just do `iptables -F CURFEW ; iptables -A CURFEW -j DROP`

Another way would be to have two versions of `master.cf` with one of the daemons disabled in one of them.  At the start/stop times, symbolic link to the relevant `master.cf` and do a `postfix reload`.

A third way is to specify `-o content_filter=...` to a passthrough daemon which you start/stop at the appropriate times.

Comment: You gave me some great ideas, thank you :)